# MySQLi LIKE query with dynamic array

Tags: mysql

I have arrary like below

> this1,this2,this3
>
> sometime
>
> this1,this2,this3,this4

etc,

I want find result from my table 
where tags like array1 or array2 or array3
or sometime like
where tags like array1 or array2 or array3 or array4

I have wall_tags have rows like below

```
this1,this2
this1
this1,this2,this3
etc
```

I have my current query is like below

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_wallpaper WHERE `wall_tags` like '%search_value%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3
```

I am not able to make it working with arrary, Let me know if someone can help me for do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see your query works 
and i added another Query that does the same

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_wallpaper (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `wall_tags` VARCHAR(23)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_wallpaper
  (`id`, `wall_tags`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'this1,this2,this3'),
  ('2', 'sometime'),
  ('3', 'this1,this2,this3,this4');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_wallpaper
WHERE
    `wall_tags` LIKE '%this2%'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 3;

| id  | wall_tags               |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this1,this2,this3       |
| 3   | this1,this2,this3,this4 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_wallpaper
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('this1',`wall_tags`) > 0
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 3;

| id  | wall_tags               |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this1,this2,this3       |
| 3   | this1,this2,this3,this4 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihwaUZpdhBvd4vhTqQAVsG/0)

Comment: Hello sir! Thanks for nice answer. I think You do not understood my question. I want get result where wall_tags LIKE this1 or this2 or this3. Thanks!

Comment: I have search value is in array . sometime its this1,this2 or sometime its this1,this2,this3 etc. Thanks!

Comment: What does wall_tags look like also such comma seperated string? You should try to bukd your where clause, where you explode your searchstrig and build from that your where clause.

Comment: Thanks! I have added sample row data which I have in my table called wall_tags

Comment: yeah i thought so, you must do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543329/5193536, mysql isn't good with comma separated columns, thtat's why we don't use them. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad